# Apply CSS To Particular Files

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, popup, font-size

I've inherited an MVC web application that administers a small database.  For most or all CRUD operations, the creator used popup screens and ajax to allow the user to edit items.

This may be a simple question, but all the font size in the popups is smaller than desired.  What's the most efficient way to simply increase the font size for these files?  They all begin with the word 'partial' if that matters.

I tried

```
<style>
   * {font-size:1.3em;}
</style>
```

at the top of each partial file, but when the user opens the popup, all the main page text gets updated with the larger font.  Thankyou for any help, I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: even doing that it updates the background text to that size, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a more specific selector. Do the popups have a unique class (or can you add one?), eg class="myPopup"? in that case, your css would be:

```
<style>
   .myPopup {font-size:1.3em;}
</style>
```

Comment: the popups are mostly item lists with a lot of div's.  Is it possible to set it once for the entire file?

Comment: oh yeah I just needed the outer div with that class. Perfect thanks